# 500 Internal server error on php GET variables (CGI)

Tags: php, apache, cpanel, httpd.conf, internal-server-error

I'm currently writing a php API returning a JSON array. On my development environment everything seems to work fine.

So it was time for us to upload it on our dedicated server. But here is the deal. While our code is perfectly working on most environments, it is not on our server.

As I'm not an expert on multi-domain sites, we decided to try cPanel WHM, to easily configure our web server. Everything seems to work well, our API default page is running perfectly, showing the correct responses when a user is not permitted. As we are using custom urls, our .htaccess seems to work as well. But here is the rub! When I'm entering a `$_GET` variable to enter the API by using the correct keys, the server is automatically responding a 500 internal error.

I tried to look at the apache log file, it shows a

> AH02812: attempt to invoke directory as script

I directly understood it was a httpd.conf problem. I replaced ScriptAlias by Alias, as most topics were saying. Now I don't have this error on my log, but its still showing the 500 internal server error.

We are currently running on Debian 7, with the latest stable version of cPanel. Our PHP version is 5.6.

Comment: I would recommend running <?php phpinfo(); ?> on both servers and comparing the difference. .htaccess from parent directories often effects child directories. You can troubleshoot them by simply renaming the file temporarily. Do you have your api script running from a subdomain, e.g. api.example.com? If so, can you serve a basic php file from this domain? Try commenting out various sections of your code. Turn on <?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ?>.

Comment: The php info is returning too much random settings to see exactly what's going on... Theres a lot of disabled functions by cPanel ! And the error report will not show anything as the main problem is that no script is read...